A question about the proof of converse of inscribed angle theorem
I have encountered this proof of the converse of inscribed angle theorem.
While studying the proof, I've stumbled upon one thing I do not quite understand, so I come here for clarification.

So, let us consider the case 1) where the vertex $C$ of the angle $\angle C$ is located outside the circle  (Figure 2a).
Note that in this case at least one of the two segments $AC$ and $BC$ is the proper secant to the circle (otherwise both $AC$ and $BC$ are perpendicular to AB and, hence, parallel having no the common point $C$).

I would like to understand why is this the case. Having an angle of measure $\alpha$ whose sides intersect the circumference so that the arc they make opposite and convex to that angle is $2\alpha$ has this possible construction for some $\alpha$.
See this drawing:

So why is it impossible?

For what $\alpha$ do you believe this to be true?

Diagrams can lead, and they can mislead. For example, the arc of the circle looks about 240 degrees, while the angle in question externally is like 25. The diagram is grossly inaccurate. This is not to do with the rationale of the proof, but just to say we would be better off with approximately accurate pictures if we're going to use pictures.

The proof gives the reason, "otherwise both  AC  and  BC  are perpendicular to  AB," which seems wrong to me. So I'm not convinced the proof is valid. On the other hand, the statement to be proved requires a definition of "angle leaning on an arc." I'm not familiar with that terminology and I have not found it anywhere except on that site. Without knowing the meaning of that term, how can we say whether the theorem is correct?

So by the alternate segment theorem we got the arc inside the triangle being $180^\circ - \alpha$, so the other arc should be $2\alpha$, that means $2\alpha + 180^\circ - \alpha = 360^\circ$, which leads to $180^\circ + \alpha = 360^\circ$, so the only case when this is possible is $\alpha = 180^\circ$. Am I going in the right direction?

In order for the angle half the measure of the arc to be inscribed in the same circle, the angle and the arc must be on opposite sides of the chord of the arc. This can be proved, but for reasons noted above I don't think the proof on the site you found is a good one. For your diagram, if what you mean is that the two sides of the angle are tangent to the circle, then your reasoning is correct and should lead to the conclusion that the diagram as labeled (with the vertex outside the circle) is impossible.

See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/192766/255730
